# Convert Windows 10 from Legacy to UEFI with Ubuntu already on UEFI

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, bios

Currently I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed in UEFI mode and Windows installed in Legacy.
I would like to convert Windows to UEFI to have dual boot.

**My disk currently**

It is installed in MBR mode and here is the [partition table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9OOg.png)

**Possible solutions**

I found out how to convert my disk to GPT under Ubuntu with `sudo gdisk /dev/sda`, but I think that Windows will no longer be recognized by UEFI.

I also found out how to do it from Windows, with `mbr2gpt.exe /convert /disk:0 /allowfullOS`, but I'm afraid that Windows doesn't know what to do with ext4 partitions, and that it overwrites the current EFI partition.

What should I do ?

PS: Sorry for my English

Comment: Might be easier to start over & install Windows, then Ubuntu, both in UEFI boot mode & restore your data from backups. I think I saw someone that tried the Windows conversion & it failed & they had to reinstall anyway. Windows wants additional partitions with UEFI/gpt. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations At minium, reinstall of boot loaders(grub & Windows) as UUIDs change, perhaps chkdsk for NTFS & fsck for ext4 partitions as repairs.

Comment: according to [this website](http://www.msnloop.com/convertir-windows-10-mode-bios-vers-uefi-mbr2gpt/) it's pretty easy to convert windows to uefi, and ubuntu is already in uefi, so I hope to be able to do the conversion easily. But if nobody has a safe solution I'll make a backup of ubuntu and use `mbr2gpt.exe` (because windows is really too long to install).

Comment: or maybe I'll just keep switching OSes by changing the bios mode.

Comment: This user had two drives so each could be different. But was not able to make it work. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2408541 & https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt

Comment: By reading the second link in your message, I saw that it didn't work with extended partitions, so I think I'll just reinstall Windows.